Equation Solver for Homework Grading
I'm a middle school Algebra 1 Honors teacher. I want to have a function in LaTeX to where I can type an equation into a field and it automatically solve the equation for me. I'm looking for something very similar to the polynom package: polynom. That is, type a long division problem and spit out the steps.
Reason: All of my homework assignments have different but similar problems. For example, one student's homework assignment may have $2a-3m=4$ solving for $a$ and another student's assignment may have $z=4a-1$ solving for $a$. A third student would have something different than the previous two. Typing each problem in and letting the software do it for me would save me a lot of time grading the assignments as I'm looking for steps shown for each student.

I used to do this using a combination of C++ and LaTeX, where the random questions were generated (actually, the random answers come first) by C++ and the formatting was done by LaTeX.  See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm .I stopped because I couldn't find a simgle other teacher who thought this was a good idea.

@JohnKormylo simple -> single?

@cfr - single (I touch type, but my fingers wander).


as I'm looking for steps shown for each student ... Are you happy with an approach that will output only the final answer for any given input or must the approach also show the (intermediate) steps leading to a final answer for any given input?


@JeffreyJWeimer Yes, I'm also looking for the intermediate steps leading to a final answer for any given input.

You could improve your question by providing a minimum working example (MWE) showing what you have in long form and noting where you would like to improve the manual long-form processing, ostensibly using automation in LaTeX. When you do not need intermediate steps, the approach by @tueda appears to be exceptionally useful in its own right. Otherwise, as you note in your comments after that posting, you are not entirely convincing that you are seeking to solve a "how can LaTeX do this better" question versus a "what tool can do (best at) this for me" question.

Got it. Thank you. I didn't put that kind of thought into it. I was looking to see if anyone had a quick solution to this kind of problem. I don't know how I would begin to formulate an MWE.

Look into the sagetex package. It gives you access to a computer algebra system (CAS) Sage, similar to Mathematica but free. My answer here has a sample LaTeX file to create a random test with answer key. Coding the steps, shown in my answer here you can get what you want. A free Cocalc account is easiest way to begin

Here is a SymPy solution with
--shell-escape.
test.tex:
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\solve}[2]{\input{|python3 myscript.py '#1' '#2'}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  x = \solve{2x-3a=4}{x}
\end{equation}
\end{document}

myscript.py:
import sys
import sympy

from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import (
    parse_expr,
    standard_transformations,
    implicit_multiplication_application,
    convert_xor,
    convert_equals_signs,
)

transformations = standard_transformations + (
    implicit_multiplication_application,
    convert_xor,
    convert_equals_signs,
)

expr = parse_expr(sys.argv[1], transformations=transformations)
x = parse_expr(sys.argv[2], transformations=transformations)

print(", ".join(sympy.latex(sol) for sol in sympy.solve(expr, x)))

Assuming that the sympy module is available for python3, the following command:
pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex

produces

Note that the \solve macro works for slightly more complicated equations, e.g., quadratic equations.

Thank you! I'm also looking for something that will produce the steps for each equation. I grade the steps as well as the final answer.

@JHBatley : That may be asking for more than is reasonable or possible unless you are dealing with a very few and  particular types of equations.

I understand. It might be easier to subscribe to WolframAlpha or something like that to make it easier.
